# Embedded Resource Dll in TFS Build

Tags: tfs

i have project that the Build Action use Embedded Resource Dll in Bin folder and xaml file Build Action=page in other folder.
notice : i have to Build just .csproj not .Sln
in TFS Build 2012 (workflow Msbuild ) i Build other project correctly but this one i allway see this error :

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "...Cmn". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [E:\Builds\17..me.Net\MyBuildDeffinition\Sources..me..me.csproj]